# Hiberate when closing the lid

Tags: hibernate

I just installed ubuntu 15.04 (3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu) on my ThinkPad X1 Carbon - 20A7CTO1WW (2nd Gen).

Hibernation works (occasionally. not all the times) with `sudo pm-hibernate` but not when closing the lid. On 14.04 I had to modify 2 files to make it work but now it's no longer working. Here are the modifications that used to work on 14.04:

1. In `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`: replace

> ```
> [Disable hibernate by default in upower]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=no
>
> [Disable hibernate by default in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
> ResultActive=no
> ```

by

```
  [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

  [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.lo
  ResultActive=yes
```

2. In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`: replace

`#HandleLidSwitch=suspend`

by

`HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`